# Does orienteering questions belong here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Does **orienteering** related questions belong here? (including questions about orienteering clubs, tournaments, etc)

I don't know the specific of other coutries, but it is possible, that in your coutry only the **sport orienteering** is known, however in Poland there are very popular formulas which pass rather to **tourism** than **sport** (mostly orienteering marches, including the long (100km) ones in mountains etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, orienteering is on-topic, it's a fairly integral part of being an outdoorsman.